# Loader for scripts and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, image, onload

I have heavy HTML-page with several megabytes of images and scripts. I'd like to show loader using javascript like Flash - with progressbar and percents.

Is there any library with input: array of URLs (js scripts and images) that makes callback when something is loaded. I know sizes of resources so I'll be able to make progressbar.

It would be better if loader library is very light or uses jQuery.
Also if it can load CSS it's great (I use LESS but should be the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery helps:

- local scripts (`url.substr(0, 7) != 'http://'`): `$.get(url, function(data){eval(data); callback(url)}`
- remote scripts: `$.getScript(url, function(){callback(url)})`
- images: `var el = new Image(); el.onload = function(){callback(url)}; el.src = url;`

And I have array with urls and sizes so I know how much was already downloaded and total size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any out of the box plugins that will achieve what you are after. However you should be able to write your own with help from [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and [.progressbar()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar).

General idea would be to show you loading gfx by default with everything else hidden. Once everything has loaded then show your main UI.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#mainUI").show();
    });
});
```

Key here is $(window).load().